# Content of div should always start with capital letter and end with a full stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to allow the user to remove words in a div tag, I do this simply by wrapping all words into `<span>` tags and target the tag, see awesome **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1mvekpx/11/)**.

So the sentence inside the div is:

> Hello world! 進撃の巨人 What isn't reality?

My question is, how can I make the sentence *always* start with a capital letter and end with a full stop, **unless** if the sentence ends with any of these characters: `.?!'")`

So if user removes a few words and sentence is:

> world! 進撃の巨人 What isn't

Then I want it to transform to:

> World! 進撃の巨人 What isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1mvekpx/17/)

```
var endChars = [".", "?", "!", "\"", "'"];

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.editable span').bind("mousedown", function() {

       jQuery(this).fadeOut(function(){
          var parentObj = $(this).parent();
          $(this).remove();
          var text = parentObj.find("span").first().html();
          console.log(text);
          parentObj.find("span").first().html(capitalizeFirstLetter(text)); 
          text = parentObj.find("span").last().html();
          if ( endChars.indexOf(text.slice(-1))  == -1 )
          {
            console.log(text);
            parentObj.find("span").last().html(text+"."); 
          }
       });

    });
});

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. The capitilize feature works, but the full stop one doesn't seem to function correctly. It adds a full stop even if there is one at the end and it adds it every time I click.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but the same problem still exists. Try to remove words until you only have `Hello world!`, it will end up with `Hello world!.`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson just need to add `!` to the list of characters to check in that `if` :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is great! Is there a way to add a number of *end* characters to the if list? Currently, I don't want to add a full stop at the end if the following characters exists at the end of the sentence: `.?!'")`

Comment: This is gold. Thank you very much indeed. Please update answer with the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much shorter solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.editable span').bind("mousedown", function() {

    jQuery(this).fadeOut(function() {

        var first = $( '.editable' ).children('span').eq(0);
        first.text( first.text()[0].toUpperCase() + first.text().slice(1) )

        var last = $( '.editable' ).children('span').eq(-1);
        last.text( last.text().replace(/[^.?'"]$/, '$&.') )

    });


  });

});
```

Comment: This is interesting, can you please update the jsfiddle with your regex code and show how the full stop at the end will end up *within* the last `<span>` tag.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson I have updated the answer to keep the `<span>` elements and is very short and efficient -- only 4 lines :) Uses RegEx too...

Comment: Thank you very much for the update, although is your approach much different in terms of performance compared to gurvinder372 solution?

Comment: Performance wise, not much faster, but it is always very important to have clear, concise and maintainable code. Also, this doesn't use globals and all the code is kept in one tidy area.

Answer (score 0):

For the capital letter you can use css `text-transform` like

```
wrapper:first-child{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

To keep the full stop at the end I would suggest adding a block to your remove function and check if the last letter is one of `!/?/.`, if not add a full stop to the last element. Like so:

```
jQuery('.editable span').bind("mousedown", function() {
       jQuery(this).remove();
         if(jQuery(".editable").children("span:last-child").html().substr(-1) !== "?" && jQuery(".editable").children("span:last-child").html().substr(-1) !== "!" && jQuery(".editable").children("span:last-child").html().substr(-1) !== "."){
        jQuery(".editable").children("span:last-child").html(jQuery(".editable").children("span:last-child").html()+".");
       }
    });
});
```

Tested - https://jsfiddle.net/e1mvekpx/20/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated code which finds the first span and capitalize its text:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.editable span').bind("mousedown", function() {
           jQuery(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
               var firstSpan = jQuery('.editable span:visible').first();
               var text = firstSpan.text();
               firstSpan.text(text[0].toUpperCase() + text.substring(1));    
           });
        
        });
    });
```

```css
.editable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable">
   <span>Hello</span> <span>world!</span> <span>進撃の巨人</span> <span>What</span> <span>isn't</span> <span>reality?</span> 
</div>
```

Do note that it is not really checking if there is any text available or not so `text[0]` will result in an error if no text is present.